# Strange LocalHost Behaviour for ASP.NET 4.0 site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a folder MyWebSite. I open it in Visual Studio 2010 and browse using the local webserver. It runs fine.

Now when I create a copy of the folder, open the website in Visual Studio and try to run it from there, it says:

This page can't be displayed. Make sure the web address `http://localhost:21926` is correct.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate application pool and virtual directory for each. Your original site name is tied to a particular port because you are using the built-in server. Better to develop against IIS.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question about running it using the local server

Comment: Your question is vague - why would you want to have two copies of the same folder/project (WAP or website template?) on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you close Visual Studio and the instance of the ASP.Net Development server before you re-launch visual studio with the other folder.

In case you are trying to run both instances together, you might get such as error.

You could also try clearing the ASP.Net temporary folders and see if that solves the problem.